# How to stretch the div across the entire width of the screen but aligning all items in the center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

So I have a Banner-component which I'm getting from a third party library.
This component creates a banner with an svg image in it (like a checkmark), some text and a closing button.

I need to style it some more so I've decided to wrap this component in my own div that I can style however I want.

Here's my code:

```
<div style={{
    transition: 'opacity 1s ease',
    opacity: successBannerOpacity,
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    width: '100%',
    zIndex: '9999',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}>
    <Banner appearance="success" show closeHidden style={{
      width: '100vw',
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
      De e-mail is verstuurd.
    </Banner>
  </div>
```

I want to style the banner to be on the top of my webpage and act as a "success" message if the user clicks on a button and an API call is a success. For appearing/disappearing I'm using the opacity & transition values.

I'm also trying to use flexbox to make it so that my div is the entire width of the screen, but the content of the Banner-component is in the center.

The Banner has an attribute "closeHidden" just to not show the closing button, because I have a setTimeout of 3 seconds that will fade it out again (using the transition & opacity).

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

As you can see, the content itself is nicely in the center (also when I resize the page!) but the div/Banner is only as wide as it needs to be, instead of being 100% the width of my entire page!

Does anyone know how to use CSS and/or flexbox to get my desired result?

**EDIT:** If i give my Banner a width of 100%, this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, all the content is to the left again.

Comment: with:100% on the banner element ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif if I do that, all my content just goes to the left again (see edited question with new image)

Comment: you then center the content inside it

Comment: Howso? Because if I use flexbox & justify content, it doesn't do anything (on the Banner)

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `Banner` has no width assigned, try to give `width: 100%` or `width: 100vw`

Comment: if I do that, all my content just goes to the left again (see edited question with new image)

Comment: Give it display: flex, justify-content: center and align-items: center too @Tempuslight

Comment: I've changed my code example in my question but the content still stays on the left of the div :\

Comment: did you put text-align: center? or add margin: 0 auto; display: block;  to the container that holds text and ✔, display: block will give width 100% of the parent's width, display: inline (such as span, i, u, a, img) will take the space it only needs

Comment: make sure to add this in the css "*{outline: 1px solid red;}" to see every container